# What is a mysql disconnect command line (why is it useful)?

Tags: mysql

I am running a **mysql** database and I connect to it just fine.  My question is: whenever I connect to the database (to add new input via php) **do I also have to include a disconnect command line?**

I ask because my bandwidth usage is growing faster than I expected so I am happy thinking that I am getting traffic, but perhaps it is growing because I connect and do not "disconnect"?

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql docs

> mysql is a simple SQL shell with input line editing capabilities. It
>   supports interactive and noninteractive use.

The fact is that the SQL shell should not be causing major load on your box. The standard practice is to just close the shell and kill the program.

> Typing Control+C causes mysql to attempt to kill the current
>   statement. If this cannot be done, or Control+C is typed again before
>   the statement is killed, mysql exits

When you exit mysql command line tool the process will end and mysql will continue doing its thing. But the answer to your question is no SQL shell should not be slowing things.

From PHP its a good idea to close the connection when you are done using it. To check out what processes are running open up mysql cmd tool and try the following to see what is connected to your mysql instance.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST`

if showprocesslist isnt what you were looking for give this a shot:

`mysql > show status like '%onn%';`

Hopefully this will give you enough information to handle the traffic load.

Comment: added some additional information about getting some more information about your mysql instance. hopefully this will help you out a little bit

Answer (score 0):

devzone.zend.com :

"Open connections (and similar resources) are automatically destroyed at the end of script execution. However, you should still close or free all connections, result sets and statement handles as soon as they are no longer required. This will help return resources to PHP and MySQL faster."

My advice:
It is a good practise to close a connection after doing the queries you wanted.